# TFTP for libvirt hosts behind NAT

Tags: iptables, kvm-virtualization, nat

This has taken me all day to work out, so I thought I would get this recorded here!

I have a LibVirt host with NAT instead of bridging for the hosted virtual machines, using the default IPTables rules constructed by LibVirt when installed. I could install an OS using a virtual CD, then get full Internet connectivity, but due to the more complex nature of TFTP<sup>*</sup> for PXE boot, the masquerading wasn't seeming to pass the TFTP replies back to the VMs.

I could see the following packet sequence from various instances of tcpdump:

1. VM udp/ephemeral to LibVirt host udp/69 requesting file
2. LibVirt host udp/ephemeral to TFTP server udp/69 requesting file
3. TFTP server udp/ephemeral2 to LibVirt host udp/ephemeral

At this point nothing further passed and the VM tftp client timed out.

I tried using the kernel modules ip_conntrack_tftp/nf_conntrack_tftp and ip_nat_tftp/nf_nat_tftp, but this didn't help.

<sup>*</sup> Although the initial request from client to server is on udp/69, the reply from server to client originates from a pseudo-random ephemeral port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found an [article about VMWare](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/215456) that had a similar problem and tried switching the type of the network interface in LibVirt from virtio to e1000. Instant success!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem as you and ended up finding your post.

On my side, loading the `nf_nat_tftp` on the Libvirt host was enough to make it work. Thanks for this hint!